# How can I batch insert a certain .txt file into every subfolder?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, batch, shell-script

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a licence.txt file into every subfolder, any ideas how to do this in windows command line?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share you work.

Comment: I've been looking however this is all i found but it doesn't seem to work  `FOR /R %f in (".") DO readme.txt %f`

Comment: @helen as a working solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1321539/1699210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run it directly from the commandline you could use:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir . /ad/b/s') do COPY "My.lic" "%f"
```

as suggested by @PreetSangha [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321480/1699210)

or in case you want to use it from a batch:

```
FOR /r "C:\SestinationDir" %%f in (.) do (COPY "C:\SourceDir\My.lic" "%%~ff")
```

as suggested by @Helen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321539/1699210)

The function of the `FOR` command can be displayed the a little example.bat like:

```
ECHO OFF
FOR /r "C:\temp\test2" %%f in (.) do (ECHO "%%~ff")
PAUSE
```

Votes should be given to the authors mentioned above.